# Microservice communication - determine if some entity exists in different microservice

Tags: spring, microservices

In a monolith application we could inject another service into controller class and check if customer exists just by invoking method such customerService.findCustomerById()

```
 @RequestMapping(
        value = "api/loanapplications/customers/{customerId}",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<LoanDto>> getLoansByCustomerId(@PathVariable String customerId) {

    if(/*condition*/){
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException(String.format("Customer with id %s doesn't exist!", customerId));
    }
```

How to achieve this in a microservice architecture?

I've tried to use RestTemplate, but getting 401 Unauthorized message with InternalServerError 500 status

```
Customer customer = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9080/api/customers/" + customerId, Customer.class);
```

I provide access token (JWT) in the request header in the same manner as for request for another REST methods (it works fine for the methods which don't require microservice communication like POST /api/customers etc)

**org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized**

I guess, that when method customer/{id} is invoked, the headers are lost, hence JWT token too?

SOLVED: I accessed the other microservice without using gateway api

Comment: Depends on how your services communicate.

Comment: @TA they communicate via API GATEWAY

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways how you can implement this. One way is synchronous(call other microservice with `RestTemplate` of `@FeignClient`) and the other way is to replicate `Customer` data in your microservice. Replicate mean that you should have some data of `Customer` inside microservice that is not Customer. When customer is added/removed/changed in customer microservice, you should send message to inform other microservice that customer is added/removed/changed. Other microservices consume that message and update their state. This message ceremony can be done with `Apache Kafka` for example of any other message broker system.